# Optimise a slow for loop

Tags: r, tidyverse

Hi I have the following `for` loop that I'm trying to make more efficient as it will have to run on much larger datasets but I don't know how to do it or where to look in `purrr` or `apply`.

**[Edit]** This function must do the following:

1. replicate 123 times (`third_arg`) `df_1` in a single dataframe,
   let's call it `Res`.
2. once there is a matching occurence of the
   variable `a` in `Res` and `df_2`, replace for `a+1` in `Res` the
   matching variable `c` (`Res$c` == `df_2$c`) by variable `df_2$d`.
3. propagate this change on `Res$c` until the end of the dataframe and
   so on for the following occurences of matched `a` between the 2
   dataframes.

```r
    library(tidyverse)
    
    df_1 <- tibble::tribble(
              ~a,  ~b,    ~c,
              1L, "a", "aaa",
              1L, "a", "bbb",
              1L, "a", "ccc",
              1L, "b", "ddd",
              1L, "b", "eee",
              1L, "b", "fff"
              )
    
    df_2 <- tibble::tribble(
               ~a,  ~b,    ~c,    ~d,
              23L, "a", "aaa", "jjj",
              56L, "b", "ddd", "kkk",
              79L, "b", "fff", "mmm"
              )
    
    third_arg <- 123
    
    
    my_function <- function(df_1, df_2, third_arg){
      temp1 = df_2$a
      Res = df_1
      temp2 = c()
      for (i in seq(2,third_arg)){
        temp = cbind(a = rep(i, 6), df_1[, -1])
        if ((i-1) %in% temp1 == TRUE){
          sub = df_2[df_2[,1] == (i-1),]
          for (j in sub$c){
            temp2 = c(temp2, j)
          }
        }
        if (length(temp2) > 0){
          for (k in temp2){
            temp[temp[, 3] == k, 3] = df_2[df_2[, 3] == k, 4]
          }
        }
        Res = rbind(Res, temp)
      }
      Res
    }
    
    
    my_function(df_1, df_2, third_arg)
```

**[Edit 2]** After some research I am making progress, I now need to find a way to have it in a function that can work iteratively for any `nrow` of `df_2`, here `1 + 1 + 1`.

```r
df <- df_1 %>% slice(rep(row_number(), 123)) %>%
  mutate(a = rep(1:123, each = nrow(df_1)))

final_list <- c()

final_list[[1]] <- df %>%
  mutate(c = if_else(a > df_2$a[1] & 
                        c == df_2$c[1], df_2$d[1], c))

final_list[[1 + 1]] <- final_list[[1]] %>%
  mutate(c = if_else(a > df_2$a[1 + 1] & 
                       c == df_2$c[1 + 1], df_2$d[1 + 1], c))

final_list[[1 + 1 + 1]] <- final_list[[1 + 1]] %>%
  mutate(c = if_else(a > df_2$a[1 + 1 + 1] & 
                       c == df_2$c[1 + 1 + 1], df_2$d[1 + 1 + 1], c))

final_list[[nrow(df_2)]]
```

Comment: to avoid having to reverse engineer your code, could you explain in a few words what is the function supposed to do?

Comment: Ok, I've updated it, I hope it makes it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

A working solution, around 3 times faster. Couldn't get totally rid of the `for` loop unfortunately... If anyone sees better.

```
my_new_function <- function(df_1, df_2, third_arg){
  
  df <- df_1 %>% slice(rep(row_number(), third_arg)) %>%
    mutate(a = rep(1:third_arg, each = nrow(df_1)))
  

 for(i in seq(1:nrow(df_2){ 
   
df <- df %>%
    mutate(c = if_else(a > df_2$a[i] & 
                         c == df_2$c[i], df_2$d[i], c))
 }
 
df
 
}
```